# how should I document my application

Tags: .net, documentation, code-documentation

We have developed an application in c# .net and aim to make it deployable within our intranet. We would like to have a solid documentation to go along with it but are unsure of the best platform to document this. Any tools available to facilitate this process?

I found out about Doxygen, Htmlhelp or Dr Explain but i'm still not convinced what to use.

Comment: What class of documentation are you looking to provide?  For application users?  For Application-support? (service desk etc) For development? (reusable libraries, or further development)

Comment: For both developers and instructions for users to setup the system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If want to generate something similar to MSDN, you could try Sandcastle (which is created by Microsoft).

You can either use the [Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) for users or [Documentation Compiler for Managed Class Libraries](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/) if your application is a shared library for other developers (although from your description it sounds like you will want to use the Help File Builder).

Answer (score 2):

If you want MSDN-like code documentation, you can also try [VSdocman](http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html).